# How to save contact us form data in magento2

Tags: events, magento2

I am new to Magento 2. Can any one tell me how to save contact us form data into the database using events and observers, and display them in admin grid under the customer section in Magento 2?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have set SMPT to your magento2 store then you will receive conatct us data to mail id which you mention at Stores->Configuration->General->Contacts->Email Option->Send Emails to.

On this if you wish to show at admin grid, you must create your own table and grid to show the data in admin and create a before plugin to the controller Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post where you save data into your table you created.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a separate module for the contact us a table, admin grid and forms.